# Unable to add custom tasks to Sails.js Gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I'm new to Sails.js and I'm having issues adding additional tasks to it's gruntfile. What I'm trying to do is use autoprefixer with Less, but everytime I call "sails lift" I get the following error:

`error: Grunt :: Warning: Task "autoprefixer:multiple_files" not found. Use --force to continue.`

`>> Tasks directory "grunt-autoprefixer" not found.`

Here's the lines I added to the gruntfile:

`grunt.loadTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');`

```
grunt.initConfig({
  autoprefixer: {
    options: {
      browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 8', 'ie 7']
    },
    multiple_files: {
      expand: true,
      flatten: true,
      src: 'assets/linker/styles/*.css',
      dest: 'assets/linker/styles/'
    },
    concat: {
      src: 'assets/linker/styles/*.css',
      dest: 'assets/linker/styles/s.css'
    }
  },
//Rest of initConfig...

//compileAssets task
grunt.registerTask('compileAssets', [
  'clean:dev',
  'jst:dev',
  'less:dev',
  'autoprefixer:multiple_files',
  'copy:dev',    
  'coffee:dev'
 ]);
```

I've tried removing "multiple_files" from the compileAssets task. I've tried installing autoprefixer both locally and globally but no dice, always the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `loadNpmTasks` and not `loadTasks`.

[`loadNpmTasks`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/task.js#L373) loads a **locally** installed module from `node_modules`.  This is what you need to use.

[`loadTasks`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/task.js#L362) loads code from of a specified directory and doesn't do things like read package.json, recurse through module dependencies, and other good stuff that `loadNpmTasks` handles.

This is why you are seeing the error: `loadTasks` is looking for a directory called 'grunt-autoprefixer'.

If you like reading source, you can see what's going on in the code just before this [line](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/task.js#L367). :)

**Also note:** grunt modules need to be installed **locally** because of the way `loadNpmTasks` works. This is [by design](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/pull/18).  I got caught by this one when I first started using grunt because I assumed how the loading functionality worked.  Whoops.

Comment: Ahhh, I new I was overlooking something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to this, I've found that those grunt packages have to be listed in your packages.json under devdependancies.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing three letters.

```
grunt.loadTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
```

should be:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
```

The former loads tasks from a directory that you specify, the latter loads the task from the directory in `node_modules`.

Comment: Right answer, gave it to the other response since there was more detail.  Appreciate the help though, thank you!